# How to make for loop that will create processes in Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm only beginner, so maybe the answer is obvious for you. I'm working on simple program and I would like to use multiprocessing  there. I have  function (Let's call it f) which is making requests on some URL. I would like to give user opportunity to choose number of 'threads' (number of functions running simultaneously ?).

I' have tried making for loop with _ variable in range of variable that user can adjust with input(), but I' don't know how to create processes (I know how to do it 'manually' but not 'automatically'). Could you please help me?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=f1)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be without `()` - `p1 = Process(target=f1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Pool` to decide how many processes run at the same time. And you don't have to build loop for this.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests

def f(url):
    print('url:', url)

    data = requests.get(url).json()
    result = data['args']

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

    urls = [
        'https://httpbin.org/get?x=1', 
        'https://httpbin.org/get?x=2', 
        'https://httpbin.org/get?x=3', 
        'https://httpbin.org/get?x=4', 
        'https://httpbin.org/get?x=5',
    ]

    numer_of_processes = 2

    with Pool(numer_of_processes) as p:
        results = p.map(f, urls)

    print(results)
```

It will start 2 processes with two first urls. When one of them ends its job then it starts process again with next url.

---

You can see similar example with Pool in documentation: [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)